# SQL Server 2008 Security, does db_datareader implicitly have VIEW DEF rights, etc

Tags: sql-server-2008

1. If a user belongs to the  db-datareader database role, does he automatically have implied VIEW DEFINITION rights?
2. If the following is executed

GRANT EXECUTE TO [Domain\Account] 
GO

..Does this grant [Domain\Account] access to all Stored Procedures and Functions of all kinds including procedures that will be created in the future (or must the statement be run again each time new routines are added?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. users with db_datareader role just reads the data from all user tables. There is no VIEW DEFINITION permission for this role.
2. GRANT database-level premission means that users recieves the given permission on database level, and this pemission will apply to SPs created in future.